# Is it possible to use propel commands in the symfony command line in PhpStorm? How?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, phpstorm, symfony-1.4, propel

I am working with a Symfony 1.4 framework, using PhpStorm as an Ide.
We use Propel as an ORM.

I managed to [configure the command line tool for symfony](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Symfony2+Command+Line+Tool+Integration+-+Symfony+Development+using+PhpStorm):

[image: Symfony command line tool, PhpStorm]

but the commands for propel are not showing up. There should be something like this

[image: Symfony command line tool with propel commnds, NetBeans]

but it is not showing in PhpStorm:

[image: Symfony command line tool not showing propel commands, PhpStorm]

Does anyone have an idea whether it is possible to make PhpStorm recognize these commands and how?

Comment: I'm working with Doctrine, and I can see all the commands. What path did you set? I use a full path to my symfony script file under /src.

Comment: I set the full path to the symfony-file in my project wich looks like this `php C:\webServer\projectFolder\symfony`

Comment: My guess is, that we are somehow deviating from the standard symfony configuration and that PhpStorm is not able to detect that we are using Propel. How is PhpStorm knowing which ORM-system is actually in use, such that it can know which commands should be shown?

Comment: PhpStorm only parses the output from the script and list the commands, it doesn't detect anything. When you execute the "symfony" script in your console, the propel commands shows up, right?

Comment: PhpStorm does some form of autocompletion though. When for example I type `s c` in the console, it shows me the available commands (as you can see in the image above). So I don't understand why the propel-commands are not shown ...

Comment: Why are you using Symyfony 2 command line tool for Symfony 1.4?

Comment: Am I using Symfony 2 command line? How do you / I know?

Comment: Did you load the Doctrine plugin in your project configuration, right?